# How to control combo box values in vb.net 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

Hello to all I am new here and also new to VB.NET. I want to control my combo box values to show all names from MySQL database. When I select name from combo box, I want to set the textbox text.

> ```
> Private Sub fnames()
>     Try
>         Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
>         dbcon.Open()
>         Dim kweri2 As String = "select * from customer order by lname"
>         mysqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(kweri2, dbcon)
>         reader = mysqlcmd.ExecuteReader
>         While reader.Read
>             search_cmb.Items.Add(reader.GetString("lname"))
>             search_cmb.ValueMember = reader.GetString("customer_id")
>         End While
>         dbcon.Close()
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
>     Finally
>         dbcon.Dispose()
>     End Try
> End Sub
> ```
>
> then i called the `fname()` function on load and then:
>
> ```
>  Private Sub search_cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles search_cmb.SelectedIndexChanged
>     costumerid_txt.Text = search_cmb.ValueMember.ToString()
> End Sub
> ```

This code, however, does not work properly. It only shows all lnames but when I select one it will set the string "2" on the textbox which is 2nd id from database and it is not changing even when I choose a different option in the combo box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where's the code of the action of your combobox?

Comment: what do you mean? i just called it in load event `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Form1.Load
        fnames()
end sub`

Comment: try costumerid_txt.Text = search_cmb.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: this one appears the selected item from combo box not the id, what i want here is to display name to combo box and store id to the combo value

Comment: try costumerid_txt.Text = search_cmb.SelectedValue.ToString()

Comment: yes i tried this one also but not working, if i return the exception it says 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'  this is it `Try
            costumerid_txt.Text = search_cmb.SelectedValue.ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try` but not working

Comment: Try putting this on page load to check if the ids are properly added. search_cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 2):

You are completely misusing the `ValueMember` property.  The `ValueMember` is the member from which the value is drawn, not the value itself.  It is only relevant when using data-binding, so use data-binding.  You bind a list of items to the control, set the `DisplayMember` to the name of column/property from which to draw the text to be displayed and set the `ValueMember` to the name of the column/property from which to draw the corresponding value.

Don't use a data reader but rather a data adapter.  Call `Fill` on it to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to the control:

```
search_cmb.DisplayMember = "lname"
search_cmb.ValueMember = "customer_id"
search_cmb.DataSource = myDataTable
```

When the user makes a selection, you then get the value for the selected item from the `SelectedValue` property:

```
costumerid_txt.Text = search_cmb.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

That said, you don't need any code to transfer data from the `ComboBox` to the `TextBox`.  Just bind the `TextBox` to the same `DataTable` and it will happen automatically:

```
search_cmb.DisplayMember = "lname"
search_cmb.DataSource = myDataTable
costumerid_txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "customer_id")
```

I'd probably also recommend binding the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` first and then binding that to the controls if you intend to make changes and save them.